# Dynamic if inside a foreach binding to do a "group by" in the view

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to group items using the following trick:

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: types ">
  <div data-bind="foreach: $root.items">
    <div data-bind="if: type == $data">
      <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice that on line 3, I am trying to filter current date based on a value that comes from the outer loop.

Is this possible?

[Here is a JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pB9Y/225/): if you look at line 5 the value is hard coded, and I am trying to use `$data` in place of "`odd`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the iterator in the outer loop using `$parent`...

```
<div data-bind="foreach: types ">
  <div data-bind="foreach: $root.items">
    <div data-bind="if: type == $parent">
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/W9AyL/)